Was the ability to add Communication (Notes) to NetSuite invoices via REST API removed?
In the past, I built logic to POST to the Notes endpoint for an Invoice in the NetSuite REST API in order to add Communication > User Notes:

It was a simple POST call to the /record/v1/note/ endpoint with a payload like this:
{
    "note": "Test note",
    "title": "Test",
    "transaction": { "id": "2213063" }
}

This code has been in place and working for quite a while but all of sudden I am getting an error when I call it:
{
    "type": "https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#section-15.5.5",
    "title": "Not Found",
    "status": 404,
    "o:errorDetails": [
        {
            "detail": "Record type 'note' does not exist.",
            "o:errorUrl": "/services/rest/record/v1/note",
            "o:errorCode": "NONEXISTENT_ID"
        }
    ]
}

Did something change that I missed?
EDIT: I found a recommendation online to use "entity" in place of "transaction" like this:
{
    "note": "Test note",
    "title": "Test",
    "entity": { "type": "invoice", "id": "2213063" }
}

This returns the same error.

After some back and forth with NetSuite support, the answer is they simply removed that endpoint. They claim it was a beta endpoint and they decided to remove it. So, as of today you can't add notes via integration.
Seems like an interesting choice to me and takes away an ability to allow our business to process invoices as we have but we will just have to adapt.

Suggest making your own restlet that does what you need. Not that difficult to write a restlet that takes in some parameters and adds a note record (or returns one etc).

It does appear to have been removed.  If you look at the 2023.1 version of the API docs and scroll down to note in the left side navigation section, you can see it there with relevant parameters etc.  However, if you look for the same info in the 2024.1 version it's missing.
No idea whether this is intentional or whether the functionality has been moved to a different endpoint.

Thanks for confirmation. At least I don't feel like I'm just losing it. I'm opening a support ticket to see if they can assist!!

Please come back here and update with what you learn from the support response!  (I hope I'm not being overly optimistic expecting you to learn something from NetSuite support... :) )
